# angularjs trigger items on same row to match user input on first column

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

```
<td align="center"><input type="number" name="test" ng-model="item.qty" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="Save(item.qty, item.qty2, item.include, {{$index}})" /></td>

 <td align="center"><input type="number" name="test2" ng-model="item.qty2" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="Save(item.qty, item.qty2, item.include, {{$index}})" /></td>

<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="include" ng-model="item.include" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="Save(item.qty, item.qty2, item.include, {{$index}})" /></td>
```

here is my html code.  can someone tell me if there is a way to automatically change the second input to be the same number as the first input and also to check off the third input when user is done filling out the first number?

Comment: I'm confused at what you are asking. You have everything here that you need. The only thing left out is your save() function, which all you have to do is set item.qty2 = item.qty and set item.include = item.qty.length > 0

Comment: how can i do that if item object is loaded from a sp, i can't load one for one item

Comment: sp meaning? smart phone, site plugin, SharePoint? Also, can you please post your angular code so I can get a bigger picture view of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather of what you are trying to do, this would be the solution. qty2 will always remain == qty, and include will be true if qty > 0.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/joqexejoxo/edit?html,js,output)

## HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td align="center"><input type="number" name="test" ng-model="item.qty" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="Save(item)" /></td>

   <td align="center"><input type="number" name="test2" ng-model="item.qty2" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="Save(item)" /></td>

  <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="include" ng-model="item.include" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="Save(item)" /></td>
  </div>
</body>
```

## Angular

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
      {
        qty: "",
        qty2: "",
        include: false
      },
      {
        qty: "",
        qty2: "",
        include: false
      },
    ];
    $scope.Save = function (item) {
      item.qty2 = item.qty;
      item.include = item.qty > 0 ? true : false;
    };
  }]);
```